# Javascript to load file

Tags: javascript

I want user upon clicking a button it will load the a txt file from a e.g Desktop and display the contents.

Can this be done?

I found a lot of examples for loading a file but not displaying it.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript in the browser can't access the user's file system - it would be a security issue.

1. Consider other client side options like Java Applets or Flash.
2. In the worst-case, you could upload the file to the server and send it back to the client - but there's probably no usecase that calls for such an expensive hack.

Additionally, check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376745/does-html5-allow-you-to-interact-with-local-client-files-from-within-a-browser) - the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) will allow this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this
http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/602

Comment: Did you read the OP's question? And posting links to remote sites with no explanation isn't an answer IMO...

Comment: That's doesn't seem like it's what the OP wants - that's about loading an HTML page into a div.

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent tutorial on html5rocks.com, 'Reading Files in JavaScript using the File APIs', that shows how to use the FileReader interface:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/