# Open a client's plain text file on an HTML page

Tags: html, clojure, noir

How could you use HTML to open a file on the client's machine as plaintext (i.e., a .cpp, .txt, or even a .html file)? I want to extract the plain textfile from the user's machine into an HTML `<textarea>`. Just FYI, I am using hiccup, clojure, and webnoir to generate the HTML and server so those are all other options to use to help the process along.

Comment: Please clarify your question, this does not make any sense. Are you trying to open a file in Clojure and serve that as a webpage? or do html templating?

Comment: when you say `open a user side plaintext file`, do you mean that the file you want to open is on the client's machine?

Comment: I'm assuming this refers to reading the contents of a file on the server into a var in the webapp.

Comment: perhaps this is about uploading a file?

Comment: Yes I mean I want to open the file on the user's machine. The file then become part of the web page. In  a specific location where the text is extruded to that location/text box.

Comment: Actually it is a text area not a text box, but I think you get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two main options: upload the file to your server to be served as HTML content or use HTML 5's [File API](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/pub/FileSystem/). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376745/does-html5-allow-you-to-interact-with-local-client-files-from-within-a-browser) also addresses a few more options (like applets, enabling drag-and-drop with the File API, etc.)

---

#### Upload the file

1. Have the users choose the file using an `<input type="file" .../>` on one page
2. Upload the file contents to your server.
3. Redirect to a different page to show the file contents
4. Serve the uploaded file's contents in a textarea on that page.

**Pros**:

- This method is pretty simple and straightforward.
- You can scan the file and do some heavy processing on the server

**Cons**:

- Trips to the server can be time consuming.

---

#### HTML 5 Solution

1. Have the user choose the file using an `<input type="file" .../>`
2. Instead of posting the contents, use JavaScript to load the file into your HTML 5 local storage (see code below)
3. Use JavaScript to insert the contents of the file into your DOM.

**Pros**:

- No trip to the server (faster)

**Cons**:

- Any and all validation/processing must be done on the client side in JavaScript. This makes your client heavier and allows users to see/modify your code (which you might not need to care about).

I grabbed this code snippet from [this site](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/), which has some good examples of using the File API:

```
function onInitFs(fs) {

  fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {}, function(fileEntry) {

    // Get a File object representing the file,
    // then use FileReader to read its contents.
    fileEntry.file(function(file) {
       var reader = new FileReader();

       reader.onloadend = function(e) {
           // Do something with the contents, which are stored in 'this.result'
       };

       reader.readAsText(file);
    }, errorHandler);

  }, errorHandler);

}

window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, onInitFs, errorHandler);
```

Comment: Best answer yet, but I don't think that this is the quickest.

Comment: @SamMercier ...What do you mean? Are you trying to do this without hitting the server?

Comment: Yes without hitting the server is the best.

Comment: @SamMercier - After doing a little more research, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty option is to simply `slurp` it:

```
(slurp "mycode.cpp")
```

Comment: I could slurp it but would that require the file to be known ahead of compilation and be server side or rather developer side?

Comment: Yeah, OP is asking about a file that resides on the client's machine.

Comment: so this answer only applies to server side files, not client side

Comment: Yes. Slurping code would only work server side to my knowledge.