# Load xml file in a directory using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to load a xml file using the javascript. I use the following code to load the xml file. The below coding loads the xml file when it is in the same folder.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET",'dineshkani.xml',false);
            xmlhttp.send();
            xmlDocument=xmlhttp.responseText;
            alert("loaded");
```

But i want to load the xml file in the particular location eg. c:/xml/dineshkani.xml

If i use the coding `xmlhttp.open("GET",'c:/xml/dineshkani.xml',false);` like this it wont load the xml file. Is there a way to load the xml file.

Comment: You can't access the users file system under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

Despite its name, XMLHttpRequest can be used for non-HTTP requests.
The following should work

```
xmlhttp.open("GET",'file:///C:/xml/dineshkani.xml',false);
```

The result status is 0 for success instead of 200.  This is because the file and ftp schemes do not use HTTP result codes.

**EDIT:** However, some browsers, including Google Chrome disable this by default. It has to be enabled by starting Chrome with `--allow-file-access`. 
So if you are looking for a cross-browser solution, you should put the XML in your server directory.

HTML5 file api does not let you access the entire filesystem you get a sandboxed directory to work with. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2378239/759019)

Reference: [MDN Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/XMLHttpRequest/Usar_XMLHttpRequest#section_3)

Comment: I didn't think that ajax requests worked on the `file:///` protocol.

Comment: I think they do: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/XMLHttpRequest/Usar_XMLHttpRequest#section_3

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks! It will probably only work when the base file comes from the `file:///` probably

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't access local files through AJAX.

You could try the [HTML5 file access API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7056216/679240), if you want.

Comment: That API doesn't do exactly what the OP wants. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2378239/759019)

Comment: You're right... another option would be to set up the page so that the user could upload the XML to the server, and then serve that to the webpage... one hell of a roundtrip, but it could work.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think it can be loaded use this link it is useful for xml file loading

[Load xml](http://www.steveborn.com/codenotes/LoadingXML.htm)

Comment: Great link! But it doesn't talk about loading xml from the local filesystem.

Comment: the link returns 404