# Local host doesn't work for loading geoJson data in Ubuntu with Apache2

Tags: ubuntu, localhost, geojson

I'm having a problem running the standard GOOGLE json file load example from my Ubuntu Apache local host.  I saw a similar question with an answer that pertained to IIS ([How to open a local file with Javascript FileReader()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30596280/how-to-open-a-local-file-with-javascript-filereader)); however, I'm looking for a solution for Apache on Ubuntu.

The json file loads correctly from the remote URL (see code below) but fails to load from my local URL even though I can view it through my browser.  I've tried absolute and relative paths.

> Data Layer: Simple
>      
>      
>      
>        html, body {
>          height: 100%;
>          margin: 0;
>          padding: 0;
>        }
>        #map {
>          height: 100%;
>       }
>
> ```
>  function initMap() {
>    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
>      zoom: 4,
>      center: {lat: -28, lng: 137}
>    });
>   // This doesn't work even though it works in my FireFox browser
>   map.data.loadGeoJson('localhost/google.json'); 
>   //This one works
>   //map.data.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/google.json');
>  }
> ```

Thank you.

Comment: Also, are there any js console errors indicating any security policies being violated?

Comment: I am new to javascript and linux - so just now installed Firebug.   

When I run with http://myserver.local I am getting this error:
"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://myserver.local/google.json.  
(Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)."   

When I run with local/google.json I get this error:  "NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied"

Comment: Correction: When I run with localhost/google.json I get the error:
"NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

Add the following to /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1        myserver       myserver.local
```

And use:
http://myserver.local instead of http://localhost

This makes your browser think it's connecting to a remote server.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I have tried this but it still doesn't work.  Now I can view the file also from 
http://myserver.local/google.json but it still won't run from the .html file.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't exactly solved this the way I wanted to - but I have been able to get everything working now by placing TestGeoJSON.html file (shown above) into var/www/html and then by loading the Json file directly using:

> map.data.loadGeoJson('file:///var/www/html/google.json');