# How to show html report from Azure DevOps artifact in custom extension?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I am storing some artifacts from my build pipeline to Artifacts folder using the below statements:

```
Write-Host "##vso[artifact.upload containerfolder=testresult;artifactname=worksoftresult;]C:\JSONOutput\finalJSON.json"
```

Now I want to access this particular json file from an Azure DevOps extension that I want to create. Like the following code give me the current logged in user in the extension:

```
document.getElementById("name").innerText = VSS.getWebContext().user.name;
```

Is there a way to access the artifacts of the current build from VSS.SDK? If not, how to access the artifacts? I have tried the GetAtrifact rest API, but it tries to download the file:

```
https://dev.azure.com/XXXX/XXXXX/_apis/build/builds/1166/artifacts?artifactName=testResult&fileName=finalJSON.json&api-version=5.1&%24format=json
```

I dont want to download the json file but I want the json to show it in the extension. Please help.

Comment: Maybe you can download the file first, and then read it using code. But it may have some limitations from browsers, check [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115057/javascript-read-file-without-using-input), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30596280/how-to-open-a-local-file-with-javascript-filereader).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my question, since I was not able to show artifacts directly in an extension, I have alternatively (for the time being) uploaded it to Task.UploadSummary using the following piece of code:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.uploadsummary]$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\output.md"
```

This is not totally serving my purpose but I am able to see an Extensions tab in build summary where the file which should have been in artifact is getting rendered:
[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your workaround here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I dont want to download the json file but I want the json to show it
> in the extension.

As I know we **don't** have such API to access the content of one file within artifact directly.

While the [Client Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#client-libraries)
like `Web Extensions SDK(VSS.SDk)` and [.Net Client Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops) support most [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) , none of them supports accessing metadata of file directly. For now only the metadata of file in git repo can be accessed via API directly. Let's check the **difference**:

1.**The API to get file in artifact：**

`Rest API:` `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/artifacts?artifactName={artifactName}&fileId={fileId}&fileName={fileName}&api-version=5.1` (The one you used)

`C# client:` [BuildHttpClientBase.GetArtifactContentZipAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.webapi.buildhttpclientbase.getartifactcontentzipasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet#Microsoft_TeamFoundation_Build_WebApi_BuildHttpClientBase_GetArtifactContentZipAsync_System_Guid_System_Int32_System_String_System_Object_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) (Use `BuildHttpClient` class)

`JS Web(VSS.SDK):` [getArtifactContentZip()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/reference/client/api/tfs/build/restclient/buildhttpclient2_1?view=azure-devops#getartifactcontentzip--)

2.**The API to get file metadata in git repo:**

`Rest API:` `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items?path={path}&api-version=5.1` Supports getting metadata if `includeContentMetadata`  is set to True.

`C# client:` [GitHttpClientBase.GetItemAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.githttpclientbase.getitemasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet) or [GitHttpClientBase.GetItemContentAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.githttpclientbase.getitemcontentasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet) (They both supports getting Item Metadata and/or Content for a single item, haven't tested it to check which is better)

`JS Web(VSS.SDK):` [getItem()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/reference/client/api/tfs/versioncontrol/gitrestclient/githttpclient2_1?view=azure-devops#getitem--) and [getItemContent()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/reference/client/api/tfs/versioncontrol/gitrestclient/githttpclient2_1?view=azure-devops#getitemcontent--)
. (Get Item Metadata and/or Content for a single item.)

**To sum up:** What you actually want is to **access the metadata** so that you can access the content within file directly. But for now the Artifact-related api is **not supported** to do such job. So I'm afraid the answer is NO, what you want is not supported in current version of API.

As an alternative workaround, I suggest you can submit a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) in our User Voice forum to share your feedback. The product team would consider about your idea if it gets enough votes.