# Accessing Local Files From Web Application

Tags: web-applications, html, air, local-storage, google-gears

I am looking into if it is possible to have a web application access local files.  The application would be akin to a word processor metaphor, making the opening/saving of local files very direct on the user's part -- they would be requesting a specific file be opened or saved to a specific location.

I've read some that Google Gears might have allowed this.  But if I remember correctly, I also read that Google discontinued development of Gears.

I've also read somewhere that Adobe Air allows this.  I've not Air though.

My hope is provide a common editing tool that can access local files stored in a version control system.  The user would have local control of checking in/out and would use the edit tool (available on the corporate web) to open those files.  They'd modify it, save it back to the local directory and then locally check it back in.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: You might want to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936736/html5-offline-storage-file-storage-directories-and-filesystem-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want real file processing or the metaphor of file load/save?
Only a few browsers support real file processing beyond traditional `<input type="file" />` upload and hyperlink download. With plug-ins like Silverlight, you can do better but you have to rely on plug-ins.

If you just want the metaphor, you can save your data to localStorage or database and show the metaphor to user. It will be easier and every modern browser supports this.

Comment: I am looking for real file processing.  The user should be able to hit an "Open" button, get a File Open dialog and select a file from their local machine to edit.  I'm hoping the user can do this without downloading a client, in order to help with adoption by the user base... but I certainly understand the reasons that may not be possible.

Comment: Then you have to upload the file to your web server and process it there for JavaScript interaction. JavaScript can't read/write real file in most browsers.

Comment: Thank you.  Not the answer I was hoping for, but the one I feared to be so.  I appreciate the help!