# how to create a html file to store offline data

Tags: android, html, tablet

I want to create a web page so that it can store some data offline. I want to use this file in tablets as well as smart phones. can any body suggest some offline data storage for HTML and also its examples and tutorials. I have Googled about websql in html5. But didn't get any simple answer.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936736/html5-offline-storage-file-storage-directories-and-filesystem-api

Comment: Simplest would be `localStorage`, which is just a persistent key-value store (`localStorage['key'] = 'value';`). But for more complex data `webSql` is good (however it's not supported by all browsers). Googling `websql example` gives plenty of simple examples/tutorials. Also keep in mind that _'persistent'_ on smartphones/tablets can mean _'until the cache is cleared'_.

Comment: can u suggest any example link for indexeddb

Answer (score 1):

If you're using HTML 5 here's an example pulled from W3Schools:

```
// Store
localStorage.lastname = "Smith";
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=localStorage.lastname;
```

[[Source]: W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

For a more comprehensive guide visit [DiveintoHTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

Or here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage
You have three main choices for storage:

- Name/Pair Storage within the browser (see the W3 link)
- IndexedDB [[Source]](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/)
- Web SQL DB [[Source]](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/)

I hope you find the best solution for your project!