# Sometimes can rename, remove a folder; sometimes cannot

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my website project. I need to rename or remove some folder by code.

Sometimes I can do all of that, but sometimes I cannot with error: `Access to the path is denied`

Try to find to solution on Google. May be, there are two reason:

1. The permisstion of that Folder
2. Some subFolder or some file in that Folder that's being held open.

Try to check:

1. Right click on Folder-> Properties--> Security: if this is the right way to check the permission, the Folder allowes every action (read, write....)
2. There are no file, no subfolder of that Folder is opened.

Why? I still dont understant why sometimes I can rename folder but sometimes I cannot.

Help!! I need your opinions!!!

UPDATE:

take a look at my code above:
I want to rename the a folder with the new name inputed in a Textbox `txtFilenFolderName`:

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string[] values = EditValue;
   string oldpath = 
       values[0];// = "D:\\C#Projects\\website\\Lecturer\\giangvien\\New folder"

   string oldName = values[2]; //= New Folder

   string newName = txtFilenFolderName.Text; //= New Folder1
   string newPath = string.Empty;

   if (oldName != newName)
   {
      newPath = oldpath.Replace(oldName, newName);
      Directory.Move(oldpath, newPath);
   }
   else
   {
      lblmessage2.Text = "New name must not be the same as the old ";
   }
```

}

Try to debug:

```
oldpath = "D:\\C#Projects\\website\\Lecturer\\giangvien\\New folder"
 oldName = New Folder
newName= New Folder1
newpath = "D:\\C#Projects\\website\\Lecturer\\giangvien\\New folder1"
```

Everything seems right, but I when I click on buton Edit ---> rename---> Update---> an error occur: `Access to the path is denied D:\\C#Projects\\website\\Lecturer\\giangvien\\New folder`

Help!

Comment: Could you add your code for renaming/removing the folder?

Comment: I had a problem where folder had to be empty before I could delete it.

Comment: @PeterRasmussen I've updated it

Comment: Could this be because, from time to time you have the folder open in your windows explorer? If you have it open, you won't be able to delete/rename it. Because it is used by you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grant permission(read/write/modify) to the user you are logged in as.
Or you can run your program 'as Administrator'.

**Edit:**
Try this.. Add reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` in your application. Then use

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.RenameDirectory("currentName", "newName");
```

Hope it helps :)

**P.S.:** `RenameDirectory` validate parameters and call `Directory.Move`. If you want to rename folder in server, you can grant modify access in root folder to IIS users. But if you intend to rename folders in client machine, you cant just rename any folder(except a few directories like a folder in temp).

Comment: @VyClarks is your app web based, or windows based?

Comment: @Avishek: OP starts wit "In my website project". I would dare to guess it's web based ;)

Comment: @oerkelens oops.. hehe :P

Comment: thanks you, I applied your code below and It worked fine, I can rename the folder for serveral times and no error occur, cause I'm always afraid that sometimes I can but sometimes I cannot. Thanks you again!

Answer (score 0):

Generally a website does not simply have access to a clients local file system. (And that is a good thing too!)

Refer for instance to this post: [How to get client file system directories in treeview asp.net C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840629/how-to-get-client-file-system-directories-in-treeview-asp-net-c-sharp)